# Consume data from Geoserver preferably use WMS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, geoserver, wms

I am working on an application that needs to display locations of boats. So far the data from these boats is in geojson and I have the following data to display the boats in my web application.

`$.getJSON("data/boatoper.geojson", function (data) { boatopers.addData(data); map.addLayer(boatoperLayer); });`

However the boat locations are dynamic and I need to feed the location of these boats from a PostgreSQL database connected to Geoserver. In other words i need the app to consume the data straight from Geoserver and I am having a hard time coming with the code that does exactly this

I have used geojson and it has worked using the code
`$.getJSON("data/boatoper.geojson", function (data) { boatopers.addData(data); map.addLayer(boatoperLayer); });`
but I now want to use wms